# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a HomeBloc

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**1、**I first defined a class that can record `Bloc` and `GoRouterWidgetBuilder`，The following collectively refer to it as: **RouterWidgetBuilder**

**2、**I initialized a map in the following format:

```
  static final GoRouter routers = RouterX.generateRoutes(
    routeMaps: {
      "/" :  RouterWidgetBuilder(
        create: HomeBloc(),
        builder: (context, params) => const MyHomeScreen(),
      ),

      "/details" :  RouterWidgetBuilder(
        create: DetailBloc(),
        builder: (context, params) => const DetailsScreen(),
      ),

    }
  );
```

```
GoRouter(
      errorBuilder: (context, state) {
        logger.e(state.error);
        return PageNotFound();
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: "/",
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return BlocProvider(
              create: (context) =>  homeBuilder!.create,
              child: homeBuilder!.builder(context, state),
            );
          },
          routes: otherPageRouters,
        ),
      ],
    )
```

I printed it through the logger and found that `homeBuilder!.create` is **HomeBloc**

But in HomeScreen, through BlocProvider.of(context), an error is reported:

`BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a HomeBloc.`

May I ask how to solve this problem: `BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a HomeBloc.`

Comment: ```  class RouterWidgetBuilder<T extends StateStreamableSource<Object?>> {
  GoRouterWidgetBuilder builder;
  T  create;
  RouterWidgetBuilder({
    required this.create,
    required this.builder,
  });
} ```

Comment: try to wrap with a Builder widget before reading bloc

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I got it through BlocProvider.of in the initState function of HomeScreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard mistake. Your `RouterWidgetBuilder` is a class without generics and thus the type of `RouterWidgetBuilder.create` is `Bloc` and not `HomeBloc`, which makes the `Provider` also provide the implicit type `Bloc`. If you want to continue using your `RouterWidgetBuilder`, you should add a generic:

```
class RouterWidgetBuilder<B extends Bloc>{
   final B create;
   ...
}
```

Also, your `create` should be a function, since the `Bloc` is initialized before there is even a `Provider` to dispose it. Because of this you can not use your `RouterWidgetBuilder` more than once. Currently your `create` object is disposed as soon as a the first `Provider` is disposed and cannot be created again, since you don't use a function for `create`.

EDIT:
If you absolutely want to keep your structure, you can move the builder from your widget to the `RouterWidgetBuilder` class, which will allow you to use the appropriate generics of the right type here:

```
GoRoute(
     path: "/",
     builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
       return homeBuilder!.completeBuilder(context, state);
    },
    routes: otherPageRouters,
)

class RouterWidgetBuilder<B extends StateStreamableSource>{
   final B Function(BuildContext context) create;
   ...
   Widget completeBuilder(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state){
     return BlocProvider<B>(
        create: create,
        child: builder(context, state),
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: Can’t work, I have tried everything you said, there is no problem with generics, and my above writing method is also no problem, the problem now is how to solve: BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a HomeBloc.

Comment: Bloc is the implementation of StateStreamableSource, I use T extends StateStreamableSource is no problem

Comment: That's the problem. I guarantee it. Try the following code:

`BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(create: (context) =>  homeBuilder!.create,child: homeBuilder!.builder(context, state),);`
This will not work because create is not of implicit type HomeBloc. Accordingly, it is a typing error.

Comment: I tried your code snippet above and got the same error

Comment: Can you show some additional code? I am very sure it is because of that. And you used `BlocProvider<HomeBloc>` instead of `BlocProvider`?

Comment: homeBuilder!.create, what I have been printing out through Logger is HomeBloc, but it is the same error

Comment: Wait a minute, I haven't specified yet, the type of BlocProvider<HomeBloc>, because I currently create it in the base module

Comment: It is clear that your `Bloc` is of type `HomeBloc`, but the implicit type is still only `StateStreamableSource`. So: You use `BlocProvider<HomeBloc>` instead of `BlocProvider`?

Comment: Since the implicit type of your object is probably `StateStreamableSource` and not `HomeBloc`, you will either need to do a cast, i.e. `homeBuilder!.create as HomeBloc` or revise your structure to match the implicit types.

Comment: Then my code has to be deleted again. If you do this, I can directly new HomeBloc. My code is in the base module. How can I modify it so that it can recognize it?

Comment: I don't know your code and therefore can't refactor it. I also don't understand why you don't include the `BlocProvider` directly in your `builder`, because then you wouldn't have your problem. Why the separate `create` object in `RouterWidgetBuilder`?

Comment: If I pass a new HomeBloc directly, no error will be reported, but if I pass RouterWidgetBuilder through map, an error will be reported: BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a HomeBloc.

Comment: I tried your latest updated answer and got the same error

Comment: Sorry, when I just used your latest answer, I missed RouterWidgetBuilder<HomeBloc>, I wrote RouterWidgetBuilder, and now it can run normally, thank you again, thank you thank you